# Why Google's SMTP changes FROM field value

Tags: smtp, google-apps

We use Google Apps' account to send site-generated mail from support@oursite.com. It was fine until some point (between April and June) the settings got changed and now when they click "Reply" they see *support@oursite.com* instead of user's email.

- in April's letters both *Reply-To* and *To* headers are filled out with user's email;
- in June's ones, *Reply-To* contains user's email but *To* header contains *support@oursite.com*.

In all cases FROM headers contain *support@oursite.com*; we try to put user's email into it but (supposedly) Google SMTP replaces it to *support@oursite.com* somehow.

The question is:

- has anyone else encountered such a problem? (yes, I've searched, not the same cases found)
- what solution did you find?

UPD: the behavior described above is for Gmail (both free and GApps) web client only. In any other client (e.g., Gmail for Android/Apple, etc.) hitting "Reply" results in the correct email in the "To" field.

Answer (score 0):

I believe GMail has been doing this for a while - I'm surprised that this started happening to you just recently.

However, there may be a solution.  See http://lifehacker.com/111166/how-to-use-gmail-as-your-smtp-server and read 'Update 3' at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Google Enterprise support says the following on this subject :

> If the From address is your own account (either your primary or an
>   alias custom from) the 'Reply-to' address is changed to the To
>   address. This is implemented for replying to sent messages. If you
>   reply to a message you just sent, you are, in effect, sending another
>   message to all the To addresses. If you change the From address to a
>   non-sending address (not the primary and not an alias custom from) and
>   the reply-to should begin to work as expected without any further
>   problems.